# Paperclip: attach already uploaded files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, activeadmin

I'm interested if it is possible to attach already uploaded files to new activerecord instances? For example I have a lot of pictures uploaded and want to choose one of them. Is it even possible using `paperclip`? I know `Ckeditor` [can handle](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/Ckeditor-integration) it somehow when used with `activeadmin`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a local path to the file to trigger storage processing from somewhere accessible to the server.

```
User.attribute_that_is_attachment = File.new('/local/path/to/file.txt')
```

Comment: In this case, attachment_attribute is whatever you set for has_attached_file :attachment_attribute